# Which .NET frameworks allow you to create Business Entities first, then Database

Tags: code-generation, persistence, domain-driven-design, ddl, migration

Do any .NET frameworks allow you to create Business Entities first then Database.
In other words allow you to use DDD / Persistence Ignorance method of backing into the database later. Any tools that allow the Models/Classes you have written to generate the SQL DDL and migration scripts.

Feel free to rework my verbiage, and make it a better question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NHibernate supports domain-driven design, persistence ignorance, and automated data-model generation.

Answer (score 3):

[Eco](http://capableobjects.com/) from CapableObjects does what you are asking for and much more. There is a bit of learning curve, but the productivity gain is amazing. Not in any way related with the company btw - just a very happy customer.

Answer (score 2):

You may opt for Castle ActiveRecord which hides the complexity of NHibernate and can create the schema from business entities with various options like creating a schema file and creating the database entities directly.

Answer (score 2):

[DataObjects.Net](http://wiki.dataobjects.net) is designed to support exactly this pattern.